# bash scripting variable in SQL file

Tags: sql, bash

I want to read a barcode with a scanner and save the code in a MySQL Database. The Barcode Scanner is connected to a Raspberry Pi and works like a keyboard. I have written two files: A Bash script to read the data from the code (input) and connect to the database (Login.sh) and also a SQL file to insert the data in the database (insert.sql)

The database connection, read of the input and insert in the database works sucessful. Can i save the input in a variable and use it in the SQL file?

**Login.sh:**

```
read code;
mysql -p host=10.0.8.3 --user=root --password=secret databasename < insert.sql
```

**insert.sql:**

```
INSERT INTO data (id) VALUES ('$code')
```

Thank you so much for any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just go

```
read code;
echo "INSERT INTO data (id) VALUES ('$code')" | mysql -p host=192.168.1.2 --user=root --password=secret databasename
```

If you really want to use `$code` in the insert script, you should

```
export code
```

in the login script after `read code`. But that will make `$code` available globally in the current shell - probably not a good idea.

Cheers,

Comment: Because `$code` might contain characters that need to be escaped? :)

Comment: Well, that wouldn't be different by passing it to a second script, but I quite agree that some sanitizing is a good idea - I just don't think that's the question here :-)